# Find position of nodes in binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to find effective solution to the following problem. Given input is: number of nodes in binary tree, root, edges and list of some nodes to find their coordinates in tree if it was drawn in a grid,e.g.[image] 
Edges or nodes on the edge are not given in any specific order, but edge that connects node to left child appears earlier in input. Tree can have more than million nodes and build tree using

```
class Node {
public Node left;
public Node right;
public int key;...}
```

is too slow. But I can't find how to represent tree in such way that it would be possible to find coordinates of nodes.
Example of input:

```
4 0 // 4 is number of nodes, 0 is root

0 1 // edge
0 3 // edge
2 3 // edge
```

And I should find coordinate of node e.g. `3` and output will be: `3 1`

Comment: Are all the nodes supposed to have a unique X-coordinate?

Comment: @radoh yes, unique x-coordinates

Comment: Is this a task from some programming-challenge type website? Can you post a link? :)

Comment: No, it's my homework

Comment: It's kind of trivial, isn't it? Use the in-order numbering for the x coordinate and the (tree height - node depth) for the y coordinate.

Comment: @Gene yes, but this way is too slow

Comment: @user2950602 this algorithm should be fast. Can you show your code? Maybe you have done something sub-optimally?

Comment: @user2950602 You're not correct. Build the tree in the obvious way by accessing nodes through an array. Then it will take at most 2 passes over the resulting tree: one to get it's height and the second to output node numbers. If the data are guaranteed to be given from the root downward, you only need 1 pass, since you can store the depth of each node in the node as it's attached to the tree. Printing the results to a file will take much longer than this computation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to construct the whole tree, since you need to know the structure of the tree to be able to determine the X-coordinate.
However it shouldn't be a problem even with millions of nodes, if your algorithm is *linear*.

The algorithm seems pretty straightforward.

First we need to construct the tree structure. I would use a `Map<Integer, Node>` when building the tree to access a specific `Node` quickly (the map will be useful later as well).(or even a `Node[]` would work fine if the `Node` ids are integers in range `0..NodeCount-1`)
`Node` class should have a convenience method `addNode(Node node)` which first adds `left` Node and then the `right` Node. It could look like this:

```
void addNode(Node node) {
  if (left == null)
      left = node;
  else
      right = node;
}
```

Concerning `addEdge(int from, int to)` method, something like this should work

```
void addEdge(int from, int to) {
    Node fromNode = nodes.get(from); // this should never be null, root should be added manually first
    Node toNode = nodes.get(to);
    if (toNode == null) {
        toNode = new Node(to); // 'content' constructor
        nodes.put(to, toNode);
    }
    fromNode.addNode(toNode);
}
```

Then, we need to assign the X-coordinates to the Nodes. I would use a recursive function, something like this:

```
int assignXY(Node node, int lastX, int y) {
    node.y = y;
    node.x = 1 + (node.left == null ? lastX: assignX(node.left, lastX, y - 1));
    return (node.right == null ? node.x : assignX(node.right, node.x, y - 1);
}
```

And call it like this

```
assignXY(rootNode, -1, maxDepth);
```

Now, all Nodes have X-coordinates, so you can simply pull the `Node` you're interested in from the `Map` we defined earlier and return its `x`

Comment: As a clearification, given the coordinates defined as in the question it boils down to `x = #nodes to the left`, `y = depth of the tree - own depth` for each node.

Comment: @WorldSEnder yes. Hmm, I have the `y` coordinate upside down, shouldn't be a big problem to reverse it though. Basically, just find the maximum depth in the tree, and call the `assignXY()` with that number and decrease `y` inside `assignXY()` in each iteration.

Comment: @radoh can you suggest how to make addNode(Node node) fast? I'm trying to construct tree going through input edges and choose left and right nodes and then do it recursively with child nodes, but it is too slow

Comment: @user2950602 `addNode()` itself shouldn't really be a problem. I've updated my answer with more details concerning the tree-construction. I don't understand what are you using recursion for during tree construction?